# make (ص) and (ع) auto complete to their full sentence.

Tags: feature-request

I'm sure you see variety of sentences for `صلی الله علیه و آله و سلم` and `علیه السلام` in English and Arabic languages.
Its very better to detect them in questions and change all of them to the best variation of this sentences.
I think the best replacement is their nearest meaning in English:

> (peace upon him) for علیه السلام.
>   (greetings upon him) for صلی الله علیه و آله و سلم

I tried to find simplest and smallest sentence to understand meanings.

Comment: related request: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/75/22

Comment: he requests to add them, but I say everyone is add it.I want this thing to have some kind of standard variation.